# Is event fired in Sprout email when entry is disabled

Tags: craft3, plugin-sproutemail

I'm at Sprout Email 4.4.9 and wondering if the plugin is built to send email when entry gets disabled status on event **"When an entry is saved"** under send rule `{not entry.enabled ? true}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you would need to create a [Custom Notification Event](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/email/custom-notification-events.html) to address this scenario.

Right now the default Entry Save event is hardcoded to match the "Live" Entry Element Status, so it wouldn't be possible to match a disabled status and have the event validate.

The Element Save behavior has been a bit of a moving target from Craft 3.2 through Craft 3.7.5. I've [commented here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/38169/115) if you want more historic context. I do plan to revisit this event and try to give more control over scenarios like you describe but I can't promise any timelines at the moment. Feel free to reach out to support if you need help understanding anything further about custom notification events. You're welcome to copy our default events as a starting point.